# Sum multiple items in 2D array based on condition (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, conditional-statements, sum

I have a 2D array:

```
[ [ 1, 2, 43, 5 ],
  [ 1, 5, 12, 1 ],
  [ 2, 3, 6, 77 ],
  [ 2, 1, 48, 94 ],
  [ 3, 3, 15, 85 ],
  [ 3, 7, 97, 86 ],
  [ 4, 0, 9, 54 ],
  [ 4, 1, 83, 16 ]]
```

This is the result I'm after:

```
[ [ 1, 7, 55, 6 ],
  [ 2, 4, 54, 171 ],
  [ 3, 10, 112, 171 ],
  [ 4, 1, 92, 70 ]]
```

Match the first index within each array, and sum the other indexes.

My first thought was to use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to find the index of the first item, add item to array if not found, otherwise sum the values.

But I really don't know what I'm doing.

```
array.reduce((acc,e) => 
      { let index = acc.findIndex(inner => inner[0] === e[0]);
      (index === -1) ? [...acc,e] : (acc[index][1] += e[1]) && (acc[index][2] += e[2]) && (acc[index][3] += e[3]);
      return acc},[]);
```

Help please!

EDIT: I'm learning! A simple change to my attempt and it worked, thanks for pointing out my error @mykaf and @trincot.

Change made to update accumulator `[...acc,e]` to `acc.push(e)`

```js
  const input = [ [ 1, 2, 43, 5 ],
              [ 1, 5, 12, 1 ],
              [ 2, 3, 6, 77 ],
              [ 2, 1, 48, 94 ],
              [ 3, 3, 15, 85 ],
              [ 3, 7, 97, 86 ],
              [ 4, 0, 9, 54 ],
              [ 4, 1, 83, 16 ]];

  const result = input.reduce((acc,e) => 
      { let index = acc.findIndex(inner => inner[0] === e[0]);
      (index === -1) ? acc.push(e) : (acc[index][1] += e[1]) && (acc[index][2] += e[2]) && (acc[index][3] += e[3]);
      return acc;
      },[]);

  console.log(result);
```

Read on for some excellent/better answers to the problem.

Comment: You're always returning `acc`, but it doesn't get updated. What's the point of the the ternary if you always return the original `acc`?

Comment: Also, your ternary returns an array (`[...acc,e]`) if it's true, but a boolean (`(acc[index][1] += e[1]) && (acc[index][2] += e[2]) && (acc[index][3] += e[3])`) if it's false.

Comment: the simple answer @mykaf is that I don't understand how to use reduce

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)?

Comment: yes, but it seems mainly about outputting a single value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `reduce` is a good way to do it, but in your attempt you never update the accumulator `acc`: the callback always returns the same, unmutated `acc` array.

I would however suggest using a `Map` or a plain object as your accumulator, so that you don't need to scan an array with `findIndex`, but can immediately look up by key. Then when the reducing is complete, you can extract the values from the result.

Here is how that would work:

```js
const arr = [ [ 1, 2, 43, 5 ],
              [ 1, 5, 12, 1 ],
              [ 2, 3, 6, 77 ],
              [ 2, 1, 48, 94 ],
              [ 3, 3, 15, 85 ],
              [ 3, 7, 97, 86 ],
              [ 4, 0, 9, 54 ],
              [ 4, 1, 83, 16 ]];

const result = Object.values(
    arr.reduce((acc, [key, ...rest]) => {
        if (!acc[key]) acc[key] = [key, ...rest];
        else rest.forEach((val, i) => acc[key][i+1] += val);
        return acc;
    }, {})
);
console.log(result);
```

If you want to optimize for speed, then you're better off with plain old `for` loops, and to support any data type for the key column, you would use a `Map`:

```js
const arr = [ [ 1, 2, 43, 5 ],
              [ 1, 5, 12, 1 ],
              [ 2, 3, 6, 77 ],
              [ 2, 1, 48, 94 ],
              [ 3, 3, 15, 85 ],
              [ 3, 7, 97, 86 ],
              [ 4, 0, 9, 54 ],
              [ 4, 1, 83, 16 ]];

const acc = new Map;
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const key = arr[i][0];
    let sub = acc.get(key);
    if (!sub) acc.set(key, arr[i]);
    else {
        const add = arr[i];
        for (let j = 1; j < sub.length; j++) {
            sub[j] += add[j];
        }
    }
}
    
const result = [...acc.values()];
console.log(result);
```

This faster version mutates the input array. If you don't want that, you'll need to spend some processing time to create a new sub array by doing a spread like `acc.set(key, [...arr[i]]);`

Comment: I really like this @trincot thank you. It makes sense to create a Map so that I "can immediately look up by key". In fact, I slightly adapted your answer because I prefer a map with keys in my project, so I changed to `acc[key] = [...rest]` and then `acc[key][i] += val`. And, as both you and @alexander did, using forEach is much simpler than what I did originally!

Answer (score 1):

You can use vanilla reverse for-loop along with the function `Array.prototype.splice` to remove on-the-fly already processed array:

The following approach it's really fast and creates a copy of the original array to avoid mutation:

```js
const source = [ [ 1, 2, 43, 5 ],
  [ 2, 3, 6, 77 ],
  [ 4, 1, 83, 16 ],
  [ 2, 1, 48, 94 ],
  [ 3, 3, 15, 85 ],
  [ 1, 5, 12, 1 ],
  [ 3, 7, 97, 86 ],
  [ 4, 0, 9, 54 ]];
  
const copyArr = source.slice(0);
  
for (let i = copyArr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  const array = copyArr[i],
        index = array[0];
  for (let k = copyArr.length - 1; k !== i && k >= 0; k--) {
    if (copyArr[k][0] == index) {
      for (let s = 1; s < copyArr[k].length; s++) {
        array[s] = array[s] + copyArr[k][s];
      }
      copyArr.splice(k, 1);
    }
  }
}
  
console.log(copyArr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your data is sorted by the first index, you can just reduce and if a new index is encountered create new sum arrays otherwise add to the last array. If the input isn't sorted, just sort:

```js
const input = [ [ 1, 2, 43, 5 ],
              [ 1, 5, 12, 1 ],
              [ 2, 3, 6, 77 ],
              [ 2, 1, 48, 94 ],
              [ 3, 3, 15, 85 ],
              [ 3, 7, 97, 86 ],
              [ 4, 0, 9, 54 ],
              [ 4, 1, 83, 16 ]];

const result = input.sort((a,b) => a[0]-b[0]).reduce((r, arr) => {
  const prev = r.at(-1);
  prev?.[0] === arr[0] ? prev.forEach((n, i) => i && (prev[i] += arr[i])) : r.push(arr.slice());
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```
` Chrome/123
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                n=8       |      n=80       |      n=800      |     n=8000    
trincot     1.00x x10m 920 | 1.00x   x1m 858 | 1.00x x100k 845 | 1.00x x10k 852
Alexander   2.36x  x1m 217 | 1.66x x100k 142 | 1.54x  x10k 130 | 1.77x  x1k 151
Ele         1.27x  x1m 117 | 2.37x x100k 203 | 2.47x  x10k 209 | 2.51x  x1k 214
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const $chunk = [ [ 1, 2, 43, 5 ],
              [ 1, 5, 12, 1 ],
              [ 2, 3, 6, 77 ],
              [ 2, 1, 48, 94 ],
              [ 3, 3, 15, 85 ],
              [ 3, 7, 97, 86 ],
              [ 4, 0, 9, 54 ],
              [ 4, 1, 83, 16 ]];
const $input = [];
const input = $input;
  
// @benchmark trincot
const acc = new Map;
for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  const key = input[i][0];
  let sub = acc.get(key);
  if (!sub) acc.set(key, input[i]);
  else {
      const add = input[i];
      for (let j = 1; j < sub.length; j++) {
          sub[j] += add[j];
      }
  }
}

[...acc.values()];

// @benchmark Ele
const copyArr = input.slice(0);
  
for (let i = copyArr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  const array = copyArr[i],
        index = array[0];
  for (let k = copyArr.length - 1; k !== i && k >= 0; k--) {
    if (copyArr[k][0] == index) {
      for (let s = 1; s < copyArr[k].length; s++) {
        array[s] = array[s] + copyArr[k][s];
      }
      copyArr.splice(k, 1);
    }
  }
}
copyArr;

// @benchmark Alexander
input.sort((a,b) => a[0]-b[0]).reduce((r, arr) => {
  const prev = r.at(-1);
  prev?.[0] === arr[0] ? prev.forEach((n, i) => i && (prev[i] += arr[i])) : r.push(arr.slice());
  return r;
}, []);

/*@skip*/ fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js').then(r => r.text().then(eval));
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I'm learning a lot! I appreciate all the benchmark info as well. Can you explain why `prev = r.at(-1)` works but `prev = r[-1]` doesn't? Also, I'm not familiar with "optional chaining" `prev?.[0]` how is that working? And finally, why include the `slice()` in `r.push(arr.slice())` I understand that slice makes a copy of the array but it seems to work fine without it. Thank you.

Comment: @TopMarx r = acc, r.at(-1) = r[r.length-1], but r[-1] doesn't make sense. if you don't care about your input data (destroy it as it was initial), just remove `slice`. also btw my approach with `sort` actually modifies the input array, but just sorts it, doesn't destroy nested arrays as they were so basically the input data isn't mutated in terms of data. `prev?.[0]` check whether the `prev` undefined to avoid a runtime error if prev undefined, returns undefined otherwise returns `prev[0]`

Comment: The downside of taking the code from other answers for benchmarking is that you risk to not take into account the updates that are made to those answers later (maybe even months later). I didn't write my answer with the idea of writing the fastest code, but as you are focusing on speed, I have added another version to my answer.

Comment: @trincot i agree a flawed approach, will update my answer anyway

Comment: yes  `r = acc, r.at(-1) = r[r.length-1]` that makes sense now, thank you. And also thank you for the explanation on "optional chaining".